How to protect a top secret python script?
I'm developing a project in a client-server architecture. The client is a python 3.12 script that will run on customers desktops and the server is a Django 5.0.x application. I will distribute the client script after running pyinstaller -F script.py, so the package has approximately 40MB because of the virtual enviroment with python libs. So, I need to protect the client script to avoid people can read my code and copy my idea.
I was thinking in to create an auxiliary script so this auxiliary script and server will do these basic steps:

Auxiliary script generates an RSA assymetric keypair
Auxiliary script sends the public key to django application.
Django application encrypts the main script with this public key and return a response with encrypted main script as response
Auxiliary script downloads the encrypted main script and decrypt with private key
Auxiliary script loads the unencrypted main script into the memory
Finally, auxiliary script execute the main script.

The problem is, even I convert the auxiliary script to a binary by using pyinstaller, if someone do something and can read the auxiliary script code, so this person can edit the code and make the step 5) writes the main script to a file on disk, instead loading into memory.
So is there any solution for this?

There is, in general, no way to prevent a human from figuring out what code that they can run does. You can make it harder (a process called obfuscation), but you can never make it impossible.

"I need to protect the client side script to avoid people can read my code and copy my idea." That's what software licenses are for. If the software license disallows modification / redistribution of the code (or even reverse engineering), you can sue anyone who does it anyways

Also, in many of cases, the code isn't even better than some open source alternative, so people don't even have a reason to copy your code

If you're working with a client server architecture then why waste your time trying to obfuscate client code? Just move over the "secret" functionality to your server and get the client to make requests to the server to do those? Nothing on the client side is secret really, as mentioned by others that's what licenses are for.

Best bet might be to re-code the parts that you want to keep from prying eyes in C as a Python loadable module. Then somebody would have to reverse-engineer object code. Not impossible of course, but a bit harder. Alternatively if bandwidth and latency permits, run it as an API on your server.

Hi everyone, thanks for the responses. @AbdulAzizBarkat asked why I don't move the secret script to the server. It's because the project is an algorithm + automation for the sporting bets. I'm using selenium to automate the bet tasks and if I run one instance of the browser for each customer on my servers, I will get two problems:

The same ip address will be detected by the bet house and they can conclude that is a bot, which is forbidden.
The server will be overloaded.

